# Can I access Outlook from Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8

We have a requirement to access Outlook through Windows Store App (Metro) using JavaScript.
Is this possible?

Thanks.
Suhas

Comment: What exactly do you want to access? Creating a new mail in the default mail program is possible via contracts, but not to just open an explicit application like Outlook?

Comment: I guess it is always possible to generate a link using the `mailto:` protocol, and let the system launch the default email program?

Comment: We want to add appointments and access Outlook Notes.

Comment: you can try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#calendar)

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/674a57ea-e7f9-4a23-87cc-f3cba4240c6f), there is no API to get/insert appointments from an app on the system to Outlook. If the appointments are server based (from Exchange, Live, etc.) you might be able to access/insert them through a web service.